# How to use xterm with -S option?

Tags: xterm

I am trying to [automate xterm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879791/automating-xterm-using-expect) and it mainly relies on the `-S` option while launching the `xterm`.

**From man page**

> -Sccn
>
> This  option  allows  xterm  to  be used as an input and output
>   channel for an existing program and is sometimes used  in  spe‐
>   cialized applications.  The option value specifies the last few
>   letters of the name of a pseudo-terminal to use in slave  mode, plus 
>   the  number  of  the  inherited  file descriptor.  If the option
>   contains a “/” character, that delimits  the  characters used  for 
>   the  pseudo-terminal  name from the file descriptor. Otherwise,
>   exactly two characters are used from the option  for the
>   pseudo-terminal name, the remainder is the file descriptor. Examples
>   (the first two are  equivalent  since  the  descriptor follows the
>   last “/”):

```
    -S/dev/pts/123/45
    -S123/45
    -Sab34
```

> Note that xterm does not close any file descriptor which it did not
>   open for its own use.  It is possible (though probably  not portable) 
>   to  have  an  application  which passes an open file descriptor down
>   to xterm past  the  initialization  or  the  -S option to a process
>   running in the xterm.

I hope this option is to make use of the input and output channels of xterm and can be customized.

How to use this option ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating xterm using Expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879791/automating-xterm-using-expect), which is again my question only!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to use" is pretty broad.  There are a few examples of its use: a Tcl/Tk script [multixterm](http://expect.sourceforge.net/example/multixterm.man.html) written a while back, and the **[`ditto`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/test/ditto.c)** program which is part of [ncurses-examples](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html).

The latter is mentioned here:

- [Get output from Ncurses app on a separate terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451030/get-output-from-ncurses-app-on-a-separate-terminal/42015729#42015729) (with screenshots)
- [Sending curses input to another terminal in C via a fifo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897795/sending-curses-input-to-another-terminal-in-c-via-a-fifo/36900885#36900885)
- [Multiple xterm pseudoterminals used as output only from multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142200/multiple-xterm-pseudoterminals-used-as-output-only-from-multiple-threads/35150160#35150160)

The option is not much used; there was some problem a few years ago which was repaired in [patch #314](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_314) (newer versions should work as shown).

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!!! It helped a lot. I explored on multixterm and able to create what I desired for.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47891237/974155